# Nativescript 6 angular how to dynamically load SCSS file into Page

Tags: webpack, nativescript, nativescript-angular, sass-loader

I have a project that I'm struggling to make work as it did before with Webpack, Nativescript 5.x, and SASS.

Before {N} 6 came out, the SASS plugin compiled .scss files into .css files alongside their scss counterparts.

I was using this feature to dynamically load device-size specific css into my pages based on the  with the following function called in ngAfterViewInit().

Now since {N}6 uses sass-loader instead of nativscript-dev-sass no css files are created, all my css rules go into bundle.js, and I don't know how to get the CSS I need to apply it to the page.

Basically this.page.addCssFile() has been made useless.

Does anyone know how to access the raw css in bundle.js, or how to configure my webpack build to emit css files?

Basically I just want to emit .css files for .scss files in /app/styles/, include them in my build and then call them as i do in the function below.

Suggestions for other means to achieve my goal are welcome.
I have tried to use mini-css-extract-plugin to create css files, but I'm not very familiar with Webpack.

```
constructor(protected page: Page, protected  routerExtensions : RouterExtensions ){

...

private setupScreenSize(){
  let screen = platform.screen.mainScreen;
  let orient  = orientation.getOrientation();
  console.log(orient);
  console.log(screen.heightDIPs);
  console.log(screen.widthDIPs);


  console.log("Current directory: " + __dirname)

  if( screen.widthDIPs <= 320 || screen.heightDIPs <= 320){
    console.log("small screen");
    this.screenSize = "screen-small"
    this.page.addCssFile("~/styles/device-small.css")
  } else if ( screen.widthDIPs <= 480 || screen.heightDIPs <= 480)  {
    console.log("medium screen");
    this.screenSize = "screen-medium"
    this.page.addCssFile("~/styles/device-medium.css")
  } else if ( screen.widthDIPs <= 600 || screen.heightDIPs <= 600)  {
    console.log("large screen");
    this.screenSize = "screen-large"
    this.page.addCssFile("~/styles/device-large.css")
  } else {
    console.log("extra large screen");
    this.screenSize = "screen-xlarge"
    this.page.addCssFile("~/styles/device-extra-large.css")
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Use [includePaths attribute in sassOptions](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader) of SASS loader plugin to include those files.

Comment: Good to know about that option, but doesn't accomplish what I need. I Have different stylesheets I need to apply at runtime. device-large style, device-medium, device-small. I know how to include them into bundle.js.

Each stylesheet has different values for padding, font size, etc customized for various screen-widths.

Comment: I don't understand why it won't accomplish. If I understand the issue here correctly which is styles are not being bundled into app, this should solve it and you can load the CSS files at runtime?

Comment: I'm probably probably not being very clear. 

I have scss files in app/styles such as device-large.scss, device-medium.scss, that are separate from 

The way {N} 5 worked was it would compile the scss files into css files before copying them into the app. You would see them listed in the emitted files list when webpack ran and access them as a file.

Now {N} 6 has changed this and there are no .css files generated or copied to the app. I don't know how to access the styles from bundle.js to apply them at runtime.

Comment: So that confirms my assumption was right. With bundle workflow there won't be separate CSS / JS files generated, all will be just bundled into couple files. It will include the SCSS files those are required (by require statement or if it's same name as your XML file's name). In your code you don't have a require statement nor a same name as any XML file's name, so webpack wouldn't know it has to include those SCSS files. Adjusting webpack configuration as mentioned above will solve the issue.